# Получение значений переменных из PHP в AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Имеется выпадающий список для выбора определенного человека, после его выбора необходимо с помощью AJAX ниже в поля input вывести его фамилию,имя,отчество и E-mail.

**Вот часть из HTML:**

```
<form action="" id="forms">
  <legend>Основная информация</legend>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Фамилия</label>
            <input id="surname" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Имя</label>
            <input id="first_name" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Отчество</label>
            <input id="patronymic" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input id="email" type="text">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**PHP код,обрабатывающий выбранного человека:**

```
<?php include "auth.php";
if(isset($_POST['id_user']))
    {
        $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
        $info = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_user, surname, first_name, patronymic, email FROM info WHERE id_user = '$id_user'");
        while ($arrow_info = mysqli_fetch_array($info))
        {
            $surname_php=$arrow_info['surname'];
            $first_name_php=$arrow_info['first_name'];
            $patronymic_php=$arrow_info['patronymic'];
            $email_php=$arrow_info['email'];
        }
    }
else
{
    echo "Неудача";
}
?>
```

**Кривой AJAX,который должен получать значение переменных из PHP страницы**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'info_all.php',
    data: id_user,
    success: function(data){
        $("#surname").data(surname_php);
        $("#first_name").data(first_name_php);
        $("#patronymic").data(patronymic_php);
        $("#email").data(email_php);
    }
});
```

Подскажите,как правильно описать присвоение значений в SUCCESS, чтобы каждому полю INPUT присвоить значение полученной переменной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в php дописать

```
$out = json_encode(array(//где нибудь перед else
    surname => $surname_php, //присваиваем переменным в объекте,
    //который передадим на клиент имена - 'surname' в данном случае
    email => $email_php,
    ...//остальные переменные
));
echo $out;
```

в JS исправить

```
...
success: function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#surname').val(data['surname']);//собственно data и будет хранить 
    //переменные в ячейках с именами, присвоенными ранее, в php
}
```

Comment: заголовки бы еще в php выдать нужные про `content-type` и можно не парсить в JS.

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо!