# Возврат значения из php с помощью ajax

Tags: php, ajax

В файле index.php считываю значения с полей input summa_1 и summa_2, с помощью скрипта calc.php обрабатываю их и обратно на страницу index.php нужно вывести в тег

значение переменной $summa_3. Проблема в том, что не знаю как сделать это с помощью ajax.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>B</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker-ru.js" defer></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
 $( document ).ready(function(){
   $( "knopka" ).click(function(){
     $.ajax({
       method: "POST", // метод HTTP, используемый для запроса
       url: "calc.php", // строка, содержащая URL адрес, на который отправляется запрос
       data: { // данные, которые будут отправлены на сервер
         summa_1: "summa_1",
         summa_2: "summa_2"
       },
       success: [function ( msg ) { 
         $( "p" ).text;
       }],
       }
     })
   });
 });
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
   <table id="calc">
    <form name="calc" method="post" action="calc.php">
     <tr>
      <td id="">Сумма вклада</td>
      <td id=""><input id="summa_1" name="summa_1" type="text" min="1000" max="3000000" step="1" required value=""></td>
      <td><input id="begunok_1" type="range" min="1000" max="3000000" step="1" value="1500000" oninput="fun1()">
      <br>
      <label id="metka_begun">1000</label> <label id="metka_begun2">100000</label>
      </td>
     </tr>
<tr>
      <td id="">Сумма пополнения вклада
      </td>

      <td id=""><input id="summa_2" name="summa_2" type="text">
      </td>

      <td><input  id="begunok_2" type="range" min="1000" max="3000000" step="1" value="1500000" oninput="fun2()">
      <br>
      <label id="metka_begun">1 тыс. руб.</label> <label id="metka_begun2">10000</label>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input id="knopka" type="submit" value="Рассчитать">&nbsp;Результат:<p><?php echo $summa_3; ?></p></td>
     </tr> 
    </form>
   </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $summa_1 = $_POST['summa_1']; 
   $summa_2 = $_POST['summa_2'];
   $percent = 0.1;
   $daysy = 365; 
   $daysn = 10;
   $summa_3 = $summa_1-1+($summa_2)*$daysn*($percent/$daysy);
   echo round ($summa_3, 2);
}
?>
```

```js
       function fun1() {
                                 var rng2=document.getElementById('begunok_1'); 
                                      var summa_1=document.getElementById('summa_1'); 
                                      summa_1.value=rng2.value;
                                      }
       function fun2() {
                                 var rng=document.getElementById('begunok_2'); 
                                      var summa_2=document.getElementById('summa_2'); 
                                      summa_2.value=rng.value;
                                      }
```

Comment: У Вас в php скрипте  round($summa_3, 2); никуда не сохраняется + чтоб отправить хоть какой-то результат клиенту, нужно как минимум написать echo <тут данные которые отправляем>;

Comment: я убрала echo, потому что не выводится на странице исходной

Comment: > Проблема в том, что не знаю как сделать это с помощью ajax. Если **очень** захотеть и ввести в гугле поисковый запрос ["php ajax"](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20ajax&oq=php%20ajax), то [первая же ссылка](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494) обеспечит Вас и знаниями, и примерами.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение значений переменных из PHP в AJAX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601137/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-php-%d0%b2-ajax)