# Выполнение скрипта PHP с возвратом полученных данных в многострочной таблице без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

В общем есть таблица в которой может быть тысячи строк. 
каждая строка это товар из моей базы  данных, и данные могут быть не актуальны. Мне необходимо чтобы в строке нажимая на кнопку я мог подключить свой парсер и вывести актуальную цену и остатки на этот товар. С PHP проблем нет. Проблема у меня с JavaScript или Jquery, я их только осваиваю по мере необходимости и в них не селен. Раньше все подключал, но не было необходимости работать с сотнями идентификаторов. 
Через Jquery мне необходимо передать переменную в сторонний скрипт при нажатии на кнопку обновить, и получить данные в этой же строке без перезагрузки страницы и так для каждого в отдельности товара который мне необходим. Как мне это сделать можете подсказать?

Вот HTML с PHP

```
<td id='controls'>$s </td>
<td  align='left' style='text-align: left;' width='250px'><a href='$goodst[link]' target='_blank'>$goodst[name]</a></td>
<td align='left' style='text-align: left;' width='150px'><a href='images/$goodst[articul]' target='_blank'>
<img class='hover' src='images/$goodst[articul]/$goodst[articul]_0.jpg' width='150px'>
</a>
</td>
<td align='left' style='text-align: left;'>Арт.внутр: $goodst[articul]<br>Арт.техн: $goodst[articultech]</td>
<td align='left' style='text-align: left;'>




        <input name='but' value='$goodst[id]' type='hidden' class='button'><br/><br/>
        <input type='submit' value='Отправить'>


    <div class='content'></div>
$goodst[price] руб.


</td>
<td align='left' style='text-align: left;'>$goodst[nalichie] шт.</td>
<td align='left' style='text-align: left;'>$goodst[dostavka] дн.</td>
```

Вот джава

````
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#myForm').submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "action.php",
                    data: "text",
                    success: function(html){
                        $(".content").html(html);
                   }
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>```


Проверял множество скриптов с разных источников, многие выводят данные только для первой строки либо вообще ничего не работает.
````

Comment: Продолжайте изучать в этом направлении, обычным копированием вы почти ничему не научитесь. Ищите примеры здесь, их можно найти ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601137/Получение-значений-переменных-из-php-в-ajax])), и в Интернете.

Answer (score 1):

Каждой строке с данными присвойте свой id состоящий из некоего ключевого слова и номера записи в таблице БД.
Например

```html
<tr id="good_1344"><td>...<td><td>...</td><td><input type="button" name="sendBtn" value="Отправить"/></td></tr>
```

Далее в момент нажатия кнопки c помощью javascript считываете этот id. Отрезаете от него ключевое слово и передаете оставшийся номер записи php-скрипту через ajax-запрос.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button[name=sendBtn]').on('click', function(){
     var row_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
     var id = row_id.split('_')[1];
     $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
                url: 'action.php',
                data: 'id='+id,
                error: function(req, text, error) { 
                          alert('Произошла ошибка получения данных!');
                       },
                success: function (data) {

                },
                datatype: 'json',
                async: true
            });

   });
});
```

В блоке

```javascript
...
success: function (data) {

                }
...
```

пишите обработчик полученных данных от php-скрипта. После чего заменяете ими в нужных `<td>` данные на свои.
Например:

```javascript
...
success: function (data) {
//проверяем, что нам пришел массив данных и он не пустой
if ( $.isArray( data ) && data.length > 0 ) {
    //Предположим, что php нам всегда возвращает массив из 1-го элемента
    //внутри которого еще один массив с полями `id`, `name`
    //тогда `id` мы положим в первую `<td>`, а `name` во вторую
   $('#'+row_id).children('td:eq(0)').html( data[0]['id'] );
   $('#'+row_id).children('td:eq(1)').html( data[0]['name'] );
}
...
```

Думаю отдачу данных из php-скрипта Вы осилите сами :)

Надеюсь мой ответ Вам хоть чем-то поможет. Удачи в программировании!

P.S Писал на скорую руку - в коде вполне могут быть ошибки.